# Spring Boot jetty/tomcat embedded access log configuration

Tags: spring, logging, logback, access-log, spring-boot

I config `logback.xml` it work perfectly
but `logback-access.xml` not work.

in maven `pom.xml`

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

in `src/main/resource`

```
logback.xml
logback-access.xml
```

**Is there any way to config access log?**

Comment: I have edited out the answer out of this question, as per [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que), and placed it into a [new community wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49964258/365237), as answers belong to answers section. If you want to provide it as an answer yourself instead, you can leave a comment in the community wiki answer and I will delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to include the relevant feature in your server container. E.g. for Tomcat add a `LogbackValve` in an `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` bean.  The `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` has a `addContextValves` method for this purpose.

Comment: Dave Sayer: I know its old post but i came across this when I was looking to configure access log for my application. Just wondering, why not use # EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties) mentioned here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html . Like just put server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled: true in your application.yml file of you spring-boot micro-service. What is the difference between these two approaches.

Comment: That's just a flag to enable the access log, isn't it? The OP wanted to configure the format of the log output.

Comment: Yes, but you could configure that in application.yml too. This server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern: "%h %l %u %t '%r' %s %b %D" will do the trick, unless I am missing something. You can also specify rotation policy, name of & location of log file etc. as well. Sorry dave i don't mean to say your approach is wrong just trying to understand when to use either of the approaches.

Comment: @Amrut if it works, you should probably add another answer explaining it

Comment: @Amrut Using logback gives application ability to send log into remote data sources like ELK or TCP log server. If you have many servers online, it's hard to find bugs if logs only exist in local directory.

Comment: can someone provide template code for configuring LogbackValve to springboot2

Answer (score 9):

For embedded Jetty you can also write this as part of your Spring Boot configuration:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyConfigBean() {
    JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jef = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    jef.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {
        public void customize(Server server) {
            HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
            for (Handler handler : server.getHandlers()) {
                handlers.addHandler(handler);
            }
            RequestLogHandler reqLogs = new RequestLogHandler();
            NCSARequestLog reqLogImpl = new NCSARequestLog("./logs/access-yyyy_mm_dd.log");
            reqLogImpl.setRetainDays(30);
            reqLogImpl.setAppend(true);
            reqLogImpl.setExtended(false);
            reqLogImpl.setLogTimeZone("GMT");
            reqLogs.setRequestLog(reqLogImpl);
            handlers.addHandler(reqLogs);
            server.setHandler(handlers);

            // For Jetty 9.3+, use the following
            //RequestLogHandler reqLogs = new RequestLogHandler();
            //reqLogs.setServer(server);
            //RequestLogImpl rli = new RequestLogImpl();
            //rli.setResource("/logback-access.xml");
            //rli.setQuiet(false);
            //rli.start();
            //reqLogs.setRequestLog(rli);
            //handlers.addHandler(reqLogs);
            //server.setHandler(handlers);
        }
    });
    return jef;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to configure this so that only the rolled files have the date  in the file name? I.e. the current log file is called access.log and the rolled one is now access-2016-01-01.log?

Comment: This works with Logback: `RequestLogHandler reqLogs = new RequestLogHandler();
    reqLogs.setServer(server);
    RequestLogImpl rli = new RequestLogImpl();
    rli.setResource("/logback-access.xml");
    rli.setQuiet(true);
    reqLogs.setRequestLog(rli);
    handlers.addHandler(reqLogs);
    server.setHandler(handlers);` Also you need a `logback-access.xml` configuration file on the classpath. Check the docs for that.

Comment: I was just trying that actually but didn't seem to work for me, I'll have another go though if you are confirming it works

Comment: Must be something to do with my jar or classpath as the log file is just not being generated. I have logback-access.xml in /resources next to my logback.xml. I'm repackaging with the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

Comment: Yes, should be ok. I also have `logback-access.xml` in `src/main/resources/`. I also have `jersey-container-jetty-servlet` artifact in my `pom.xml`.

Comment: Going to create a new question as really not sure why this doesn't work. I can test that the resource is there. Get no logs / errors so hard to know what's up.

Comment: I worked out the problem - has it really been over 5 hours :( See my answer below/above.

Answer (score 6):

After many hours of trying to get a solution to work with SpringBoot 1.4 + Jetty + Logback-access I have finally found an answer to my woes.

Jetty's API interface changed in v9.3 and Logback-access no longer works.

http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/Jetty-9-3-access-logging-recommended-configuration-td7620755.html

There has been a pull request in the Logback project to get it to work again.

https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/pull/269

There a couple of solutions which are mentioned in the above pull request.

**Option 1**.

Use the org.eclipse.jetty.server.Slf4jRequestLog implementation to route the logging configuration back to classic Logback.

JettyConfiguration @Bean

```
RequestLogHandler requestLogsHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
requestLogsHandler.setServer(server);
Slf4jRequestLog log = new Slf4jRequestLog();
log.setLoggerName("com.example.accesslog");
requestLogsHandler.setRequestLog(log);
handlers.addHandler(requestLogsHandler);
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

logback.xml

```
<appender name="FILE-ACCESS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_PATH}/main.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <!-- You'll have to work this out -->
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/main.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log
        </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>20MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="com.example.accesslog">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ACCESS" />
</logger>
```

This works but you lose all the access log specific parameters in the custom PatternLayout available with Logback-access. You probably need to roll your own pattern classes.

Thought this might work but it didn't (or I didn't do it properly).

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.access.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%h %l %u [%t] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}"</pattern>
        </layout>
</encoder>
```

**Option 2**

Also alluded to in the pull request above is a fix of the issue which can be used until it gets sorted.

Create a class that adds the missing interface and use that instead of RequestLogImpl.

New class

```
package com.example.ch.qos.logback.access.jetty;

import ch.qos.logback.access.jetty.RequestLogImpl;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.LifeCycle;

public class LogbackAccessRequestLogImplFix1052 extends RequestLogImpl implements LifeCycle {
```

}

Jetty Configuration @Bean

```
RequestLogHandler requestLogs = new RequestLogHandler();
requestLogs.setServer(server);
LogbackAccessRequestLogImplFix1052 rli = new LogbackAccessRequestLogImplFix1052();
rli.setResource("/logback-access.xml");
rli.setQuiet(false);
requestLogs.setRequestLog(rli);
handlers.addHandler(requestLogs);
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

I tried both and ended up going with option 2 for now as I have spent tooooooooo long on this already. I would prefer option 1 though so I can keep all my logging config in the same file.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this up! I've just realized I might also be affected by this as I recently upgraded to Jetty 9.3. Hope this gets a fix soon.

Comment: Use the encoder pattern  <pattern>%msg</pattern>. Call the slf4jRequestLog.setExtended(true) to get the extended format. No need to fiddle with doing your own pattern if you want the standard format.

Answer (score 1):

This version of programmatically [adding a Tomcat valve for logback-access](https://github.com/wacai/spring-boot-starter-logback-access/blob/master/src/main/java/com/wacai/springboot/logback/access/LogbackAccessConfiguration.java) improves on the author's original solution a bit.

Thanks to wacai for that. Here is my version that

- removes the trailing `:` from `${logback.access.config.path:}`
- assumes `src/main/resources/logback-access.xml`
- removes configuration option to change the name of `logback-access.xml`
- works in Spring Boot 1.3.3

NOTE: you need logback-access 1.1.6 to load config from resources - automatically searches resources for `logback-access.xml`.

```
import ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatContextCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class LogbackAccessEventConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {

        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
                if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                    ((TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                            .addContextCustomizers(new TomcatContextCustomizer() {

                                @Override
                                public void customize(Context context) {
                                    LogbackValve logbackValve = new LogbackValve();
                                    logbackValve.setFilename("logback-access.xml");
                                    context.getPipeline().addValve(logbackValve);
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way is to register Servlet Filter and write to regular log.

To prevent mixing access events with other events disable `additivity`:

```
<appender name="ACCESS-LOG"
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./log/evilAccess.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %msg ip=%mdc{ip} session=%mdc{session} user=%mdc{user}%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>./log/evilAccess-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="com.evil.web.log.MyAccessLogFilter" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS-LOG" />
</logger>

<logger name="com.evil.web.log.MyAccessLogFilter" level="debug" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="ACCESS-LOG" />
</logger>
```

`LoggingFilter` is regular Servlet Filter, which can be easily registered in Spring Boot app via `@ServletComponentScan` on `@Configuration` class + `@WebFilter` on `implements javax.servlet.Filter` or via bean config:

```
@Bean
myAccessLogFilter myAccessLogFilter() {
    SaAccessLogFilter filter = new MyAccessLogFilter();
    // filter.setMaxPayloadLength(100);
    return filter;
}

@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean registration() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(myAccessLogFilter());
    registration.setOrder(1);
    registration.setEnabled(true);
    return registration;
}
```

I recommend to use at least `GenericFilterBean` or better `OncePerRequestFilter`. Some logging filters already provided by Spring Web inside `org.springframework.web.filter` package:

- `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter`
- `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`
- `ServletContextRequestLoggingFilter`

I define own implementation based on `OncePerRequestFilter` to fill Slf4j MDC context with IP address and other information...

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587186/365237), cortesy of [Ego Slayer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2818874/ego-slayer), posted as community wiki:

---

I get start from http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

just create file here `src/main/java/hello/MyConfig.java`

```
package hello;

import org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer(){
        return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {
            @Override
            public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory) {

                if(factory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory){
                    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) factory;

                    LogbackValve  logbackValve = new LogbackValve();
                    logbackValve.setFilename("src/main/resources/logback-access.xml");
                    containerFactory.addContextValves(logbackValve);


                }

            }
        };
    }
}
```

and add `logback-access` in maven `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>2.3.2</version> 
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case we updated a project from SpringBoot 1.3.0 to 1.5.16.RELEASE that comes with Jetty v9.x+ which broke the generation of logback access log as reported earlier in this thread. To fix the issue we did following steps -

1. Added [logback-access-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/akihyro/logback-access-spring-boot-starter) in dependencies, along with logback-classic and logback-core.
2. Added following code in my JettyConfig

```
   @Bean
RequestLog makeRequestLog() {
    RequestLog requestLog = new Jetty93RequestLogImpl()
    requestLog.resource = '/logback-access.xml'
    requestLog
}
// Jetty 9.x
private static class Jetty93RequestLogImpl extends RequestLogImpl implements LifeCycle {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example using Spring boot 2(2.1.4.RELEASE). Works well for me.

```
@Component
public class JettyCustomizationConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableJettyWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableJettyWebServerFactory server) {
        server.addServerCustomizers(customJettyServer());
    }

    private JettyServerCustomizer customJettyServer() {
        return server -> {
            HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
            RequestLogHandler requestLogHandler = new RequestLogHandler();
            requestLogHandler.setServer(server);
            RequestLogImpl requestLog = new RequestLogImpl();
            requestLog.setResource("/logback-access.xml");
            requestLog.setQuiet(false);
            requestLog.start();
            requestLogHandler.setRequestLog(requestLog);
            handlers.addHandler(server.getHandler());
            handlers.addHandler(requestLogHandler);
            server.setHandler(handlers);
        };
    }
}
```

logback-access.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
    <property name="log.path" value="logs" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.path}/requests/seastar_request_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would you like to update with details about RequestLogImpl?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone:

In addition to configuring the LogbackValve like so

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
    tomcat.addContextValves(new LogbackValve());

    return tomcat;
}
```

I also had to place `logback-access.xml` under `src/main/resources/conf`. If I placed it in `src/main/resources` it was NOT loaded automatically.

This is using Spring Boot v2.5.2 and logback-access v1.2.5.